# Prevent SVG slices from fragmenting objects on the slice edges

Tags: svg, slice

I always find the best answers on SE, so here is a problem that has me stumped that someone on this site probably knows the solution.

I have a large Illustrator file (a map) that I slice onto 128 equal pieces (with HTML) for the web with an older version of Illustrator (newer versions don't offer this). These slices are "reassembled" on my web page as they are viewed.

Thing is, sometimes the art pieces on the slice edges fragment. For example there might be a number of *smaller illustrations* that fall on the edge of two slices. Sometimes these *smaller illustrations* appear correctly when "reassembled" for viewing on the web page, sometimes only incomplete pieces appear.

I believe the solution is to have the complete *smaller illustration* to be present in both SVG slices so that whichever slice is being read the entire *smaller illustration* will appear, but have not found a way to ensure this. I have tried grouping the *smaller illustrations* but that doesn't seem to work.

The layout of the slices is over my head, so I am not looking to recode the site. Besides I have been able to successfully update the slices on a couple of occasions. Just not always.

Would someone please consider my problem? Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

TomH

Comment: Can you post an image of what you mean by "fragmenting"?  It's hard to tell what you mean from your description.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to have 128 svg files that I would want to dynamically align in the HTML page, I probably would attempt to load them in a specific order. For instance, I would call the 'next' file after the onload of the previous has fired. Sounds like a plan? :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a tool for something it's not intended to do.  Slicing or tiling a large image into smaller pieces is commonly used to break down raster (pixel-based) images, but it doesn't make much sense for SVG.  An SVG `<circle>` or `<rectangle>` or `<path>` is a single element even if it may be drawn across multiple tiles.  For SVG, if you have a very large file there are other ways to break it up into multiple files, usually with layers of different types of elements.

Duplicating any elements that cross over a cut line should work to ensure they show up in the final product, that isn't going to be an easy thing to code, especially considering that you're currently using an Inkscape function to do the work.

In the meantime, however, you could simply try changing the CSS to let the SVG overflow its borders.  That way, so long as every element is defined in one of your tiles they should be drawn in their entirety on the screen.  However, you'll find that Webkit browsers (Chrome, Opera) will only let an SVG overflow into it's own padding space, so you'll need to give each tile sufficient padding to cover the cropped elements, then cancel out the padding with negative margins:

```
svg.map-tile {
    overflow:visible;
    padding:50%;
    margin:-50%;
}
```

You don't specify how your tiles are being laid out on the page, so I hope that playing around with margins and paddings doesn't throw that off.

Comment: Amelia,I did find a solution that effectively is "Duplicating any elements that cross over a cut line". I made each illustration into a Symbol. Now, Illustrator has the entire symbol on any crossovers of adjacent slices. Thx.